# Ubuntu 21.04 kernel panic (5.11.0-40 and 5.11.0-40)

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

Both kernel versions don't work, recovery mode or not. The computers a lenovo thinkpad T490 with ubuntu pre-installed. I have no idea what to do now.. GRUB version is 2.04. The slack trace indicates a kernel panic after trying to kill init!.. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Keep in mind this is a work computer, I can't delete the data on it.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 is rapidly approaching its End-of-Life date. You should be thinking about a release upgrade ASAP. That alone will likely fix the problem.

Comment: How can I if I can't even enter my system.. I'm stuck on boot

Comment: There are ways using a live USB but first you should try to boot with an early kernel and from there fully update the system. That also should fix the issue.

Comment: I only have 2 kernel versions and both cause a kernel panic

Comment: I suggest you contact your IT support. We don't want to be responsible for anything that may result from giving other possible solutions.

Comment: I need it working asap. Is it possible to install an older version of the kernel to fix this problem ? it seems like /sbin/init is missing in grub for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132144/discussion-between-ulysse-corbeil-and-changanauto).